# CollapsingToolbar layout not scrolling

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a collapsingtoolbarLayout i have included that in my linear layout after i designed the page i noticed that the collapsing toolbar layout is not scrolling.i am not able to scroll the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/changedImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/dinesh"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How to make it scrollable??

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove LinearLayouts inside CoordinatorLayout to make it scrollable.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/changedImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/dinesh"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->
    <!--</LinearLayout>-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And if you want to show the `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar`, you need to set a `NoActionBar` theme to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` such as:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

and add below code to `onCreate` of the activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: If i remove the linear layout the views below my collapsing toolbar are taken to top

Comment: You need to set `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` for the layout below of the `AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed
```

to your toolbar(you have added it in CollapsingToolbarLayout. add it inside Toolbar also)

I have added it. see below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/changedImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/dinesh"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
```

> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed

```
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```